# web scraping of webpage on chartink.com

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please help me to scrape this link.
link - https://chartink.com/screener/time-pass-48
I am trying to web scrape but it is not showing the table which I want. please help me the same.

I have tried this code, but it is not giving me the desired result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://chartink.com/screener/time-pass-48'
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Comment: It looks like you'll probably need to use Selenium to scrape that link.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data indeed comes from a POST request. You don't need to allow JavaScript to run. You simply need to pick up one cookie (`ci_session` - which can be done using Session object to hold cookies from initial landing page request to pass on with subsequent POST), and one token (`X-CSRF-TOKEN` - which can be pulled from a `meta` tag in the initial request response):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

data = {
  'scan_clause': '( {cash} ( monthly rsi( 14 ) > 60 and weekly rsi( 14 ) > 60 and latest rsi( 14 ) > 60 and 1 day ago  rsi( 14 ) <= 60 and latest volume > 100000 ) ) '
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://chartink.com/screener/time-pass-48')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    s.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = soup.select_one('[name=csrf-token]')['content']
    r = s.post('https://chartink.com/screener/process', data=data).json()
    #print(r.json())
    df = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
    print(df)
```

Comment: thank you sir , thank you very much , but please tell me 1 thing that your code is showing 33 extra stocks which are not in the screener , why ?

Comment: Is there more than 1 page of results on website?

Comment: yes sir , but i want all pages . except that your code is showing me 1-2 stocks extra daily . and in previous comment it was a typo , that 3 extra stocks were shown. not 33.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Comment: Any way to pass `data ` variable from csv to fetch different scanner result

Comment: I want to loop values for data variable as List. but it returns empty df

Comment: You Deserve a Medal! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the table data by making a `post` request. You can have a look in the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab and see which elements are loading from elsewhere.

The data from the table is loading from `https://chartink.com/screener/process` post request (*look at the 'process' name in the network tab*). You can make a [`post` request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) using the `requests` library as [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68189326/15164646) suggested.

---

Alternatively, you can achieve this without making things complicated by using `requests-html` library even though it will be much faster by getting data directly from the source, e.g. making a `post` request.

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://chartink.com/screener/time-pass-48')
# renders javascript
response.html.render()

for result in response.html.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr'):
    print(f'{result.text}\n')

# part of the output:
'''
1
Kothari Products Limited
KOTHARIPRO
P&F | F.A
19.96%
106.7
262,997
'''
```

And from there all needs to be done is to `split()` elements and get the desired element (`index`), e.g:

```py
for result in response.html.xpath('//*[@id="DataTables_Table_0"]/tbody/tr'):
    # getting text data, splitting by a new line and grabbing first index [1]
    # the process is the same for every other column
    stock_name = result.text.split('\n')[1]
    print(stock_name)

# part of the output:
'''
Kothari Products Limited
STEELXIND
Oswal Chemicals & Fertilizers Limited
Hbl Power Systems Limited
'''
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ayush/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 6, in <module>
    response.html.render()
  File "C:\Users\Ayush\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 598, in render
    content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url, script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html, reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout, keep_page=keep_page))

Comment: i am getting error for response.html.render

Comment: @ayush5624 seems like pyppeteer [wasn't installed properly](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#javascript-support). The first time you ever run the `render()` method, it will download Chromium into your directory.

Comment: so what should i do to install it again sir ?

Comment: @ayush5624 try to uninstall  `pyppeteer` and install manually via [`pip install pyppeteer`](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) or look for `pyppeteer` in the Pycharm packages (Settings  -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> Click on + icon)

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import bs4
page = requests.get("https://chartink.com/screener/time-pass-48")
bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')
```

I think this should do it.

Comment: sir , i got the same  html page which i got from my code but not the desired table.

Comment: Sir is it legal to access or read Chartlink response as JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the data Scan clause as below. However, I'm getting an empty dataframe! what part of the code should be changed?

```
data = {
  'scan_clause': '( {cash} ( latest close > 10 and latest tema(latest close,10) > latest tema( latest close,20) and latest volume > 50000 and market cap > 500) ) '
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://chartink.com/screener/tema-swing-buy')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    s.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = soup.select_one('[name=csrf-token]')['content']
    r = s.post('https://chartink.com/screener/process', data=data).json()
    #print(r.json())
    df = pd.DataFrame(r['data'])
    print(df)
```